# Building a custom Counter function without using built-ins

Tags: python, function, counter, frequency

I have this code:

```
L = [1, 4, 7, 5, 5, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1]

def frequency(L):
    counter = 0
    number = L[0]
    for i in L:
        amount_times = L.count(i)
        if amount_times > counter:
            counter = amount_times
            number = i
    return number

print(frequency(L))
```

But I don't want to use counter function. I want to make code run without any built-in functions. How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you want that? You could also use import collections Counter but you probably just want more for loops.

Comment: it all std lib functions and language build-in data objects, you can implement `count` in some other ways as you like

Comment: because I have homework and we can't use built-in function

Comment: Output will be consistent most frequency number or string.
if input 1 1 1 2 2 3, most frequency is; 1. and output is 1...

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to reinvent `collections.Counter`, this is possible with and without `list.count`. However, I see no rationale.

Using `list.count`, you can use a dictionary comprehension. This is inefficient as the list is passed once for each variable.

```
def frequency2(L):
    return {i: L.count(i) for i in set(L)}
```

---

If you do not wish to use `list.count`, this is possible using `if` / `else`:

```
def frequency3(L):
    d = {}
    for i in L:
        if i in d:
            d[i] += 1
        else:
            d[i] = 0
    return d
```

Then to extract the highest count(s):

```
maxval = max(d.values())
res = [k for k, v in d.items() if v == maxval]
```

Comment: second code exactly as I want. but I want to from code that shows us just most frequency number. So I mean, just "1" ın that code above.

Comment: OK, see update. If you want to reinvent `max`, another answer will be better.

Comment: I want too much thing sorry. but that code not suit for me, because ready  code not free in my school :/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one. Not sure if this one is acceptable to you.

This finds the most frequent item in a list without using built-ins:

```
L = [1, 4, 7, 5, 5, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1]

def frequency(L):
    count, item = 0, ''
    d = {i:0 for i in L}
    for i in L[::-1]:
         d[i] = d[i] + 1
         if d[i] >= count :
             count = d[i]
             item = i
    return item

print(frequency(L))
# 1
```

Comment: this is very good. but I didn't see in my school; {}
can I use [] or "". I mean list or string. can I use? --> d = {} ---> d = []

Comment: No, `{}` with keys and values is dictionary and `[]` is a list. Learn more on dictionaries. The one above `d = {....}` is called a dictionary comprehension, I don't know if that's part of your school curriculum.